# Solve $(z+ \bar{z}=|z^2+1|)$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Solve this equation: $$z+ \bar{z}=|z^2+1|$$

I tried the following.
$$x+iy+x-iy=|z^2+1|$$
$$2x=|z^2+1|$$
$$x=(|z^2+1|)/2$$
and I came to a dead end.

How can I proceed?

Comment: $|z^2+1| \neq |x^2+1|$

Comment: Breaking up $z$ into its real and imaginary parts is a good approach, you just need to continue in that fashion on the right hand side, e.g. $|z^2 + 1| = \ldots$ ?

Comment: sry is yet another typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints**: $$z^2+1=(x+iy)^2+1=(x^2-y^2+1)+i(2xy)$$ $$|a+ib|^2=a^2+b^2$$

Comment: if I understand your suggestion then the result should be $ x ^ 2 + y ^ 2 +2 x +1 = $ 0 or a circle, right?

Comment: @malloc: How do you get that? I end up with a fourth-degree curve.

Comment: @malloc: I'm afraid it isn't that simple, no. Squaring both sides of $$2x=|z^2+1|$$ will give you $$4x^2=(x^2-y^2+1)^2+4x^2y^2,$$ which is more complicated.

Comment: should not be  $-4x^2y^2$?

Comment: No. $(2xy)^2=4x^2y^2$. The $i$ is not included in the squaring. If it were as you say, then (for example) $$1=1^2=|i|^2=i^2=-1.$$

Comment: @malloc: Henning makes a good point. Once you expand $(x^2-y^2+1)^2$ and gather all your variables on one side, you should be able to show that the expression on one side is a perfect square, while the expression on the other is $0.$ Taking the square root will give you your solution: a circle.

Comment: @Henning: Thanks for the input!

Comment: Actually, I take everything back. I had an algebra mistake along the way.

Comment: I'm still a little confused(sry I'm a newbie :)). I did all the calculations and finally get $$(x^2+y^2-1)^2$$ that should be correct! Now what I'm missing?

Comment: @malloc: Perfect! So you have $(x^2+y^2-1)^2=0,$ so $x^2+y^2-1=0,$ and so $x^2+y^2=1.$ Since $x$ is non-negative by the original equation, what can you conclude?

Comment: ahhhhhh ok got it! but the circle on walfram is not too big? It should have $r=1$!

Comment: @malloc: I'm not sure what you mean. Post a link?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=z%2B%28z*%29%3D|%28z^2%29%2B1|

Comment: @malloc: The plot on Wolfram is under the assumption that $z$ is *real*. The only solution there is $z=1.$ Ignore it.

Comment: ahh ok! Thanks!

Comment: @malloc: By the way, even if you don't accept Henning's answer (though I would, if I were you), I definitely recommend that you take a good look at it. That approach is much less complicated than splitting into parts, and makes the process almost trivial.

Comment: yes i know, infact I'm studying his version!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of splitting into real and imaginary parts, one can also square the original equation and get
$$ (z+\bar z)^2  = (z^2+1)\overline{(z^2+1)} = (z^2+1)(\bar z^2+1) $$
(where the second equals sign is because conjugation is an isomorphism).

After multiplying out, the $z^2$ and $\bar z^2$ terms cancel out and we're left with
$$ (z\bar z)^2 - 2z\bar z + 1 = 0 $$
which factors as
$$ (z\bar z-1)^2 = 0 $$

---

Here's a diagram that shows geometrically that the equation is indeed true on the right half of the unit circle. The three congruent right triangles show that the distance to $z^2+1$ is twice the real part of $z$.

[image: diagram goes here]